# How to set up RSpec to use locale by default in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a newsly started rails application and I scaffolded the project using Rspec as well so it generated lots of tests. But all these tests in `spec/routing` folder are failing.
Here is my `my_models_routing_spec.rb` file:

```
RSpec.describe MyModelController, type: :routing do
  describe "routing" do
    it "routes to #index" do
      expect(get: "/my_models").to route_to("my_models#index")
    end
  end
end
```

and here is the error message:

```
1) MyModelController routing routes to #index
     Failure/Error: expect(get: "/my_model").to route_to("my_model#index")
       No route matches "/my_model"
     # ./spec/routing/my_model_routing_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
```

I think this is because my routes are scoped into locale:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root to: "home#index"
    resources :my_models
  end
  get "/*path", to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}", status: 302),
                constraints: { path: /(?!(#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")})\/).*/ },
                format: false

end
```

This is the case for all of the tests. Is there a way to configure Rspec to take locale into consideration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to test your routes, then why not test it with all available locales?
Something like this:

```rb
RSpec.describe MyModelController, type: :routing do
  describe "routing" do
    it "routes to #index" do
      I18n.availble_locals.each do |locale|
        expect(get: "#{locale}/my_models").to route_to("my_models#index")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

OR you could test the paths like this:

```rb
RSpec.describe MyModelController, type: :routing do
  describe "routing" do
    it "routes to #index" do
      expect(get: my_models_path).to route_to("my_models#index")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at @Hacman's code, I found the solution. I post the version that worked for me. Thanks to Hackman.

```
RSpec.describe MyModelController, type: :routing do
  describe "routing" do
    I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
      it "routes to #index" do
        expect(get: "#{locale}/my_model", ).to route_to("my_model#index", locale: "#{locale}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```